# django вывод доп информации при помощи шаблонизатора

Tags: django, шаблонизаторы

Учусь программированию, изучаю django.
Имеется две модели Bb и Rubric.

```
class Bb(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length = 50, verbose_name = 'Устройство')
content = RichTextUploadingField()
price = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Не трогать')
published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, db_index = True, verbose_name = 'Опубликовано')
rubric = models.ForeignKey('Rubric', null = True, on_delete = models.PROTECT, verbose_name = 'Тип устройства')
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d', verbose_name='Ссылка картинки')

class Rubric(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, db_index = True, verbose_name = 'Название')
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

На странице сайта создал шаблон

```
<div class="1 " id="content-2">
        {% for rubric in rubrics %}
        <a class="btn" href="{% url 'by_rubric' rubric.pk %}">{{ rubric.name }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}  
    </div>
```

Сам {% block content %} {% endblock %} ссылается на htm файл в котором прописано {{bb.title}}, т.е. название товара из класса bb.

***Вопрос***, как при нажатии на имя товара(bb.title) вывести оставшуюся о нём информацию из бд(content, rubric, image)?

Comment: Самый каноничный способ "из учебника" при нажатии перейти на отдельную страницу с помощью detail view, где выводятся все нужные  данные по одному объекту. Если на этой же странице, то догружать данные Ajax запросом или просто скрывать часть данных до нажатия на title. Какой вариант интересней?

Comment: Спасибо, даже не знаю, давай что попроще через нажатия на title. Мне надо на этой же странице вывести.